# Perl Getopt Configure Issues

Tags: perl, getopt

```
#test.pl

use Getopt::Long;
Getopt::Long::Configure ("bundling");

GetOptions ( 'TestB|B|b' => \$testb ,
             'TestA|A|a' => \$testa, );
```

Here is my situation  i may exute `perl test.pl -Ba`

so i use `Getopt::Long::Configure ("bundling");`

Because of this my program is getting slowed initally even i tryed to execute with options 
`perl test.pl`

is there any best way slove this ?

Benchmark Results :

```
with Getopt::Long::Configure ("bundling");

real    0m6.101s
user    0m2.040s
sys     0m0.260s

Without Getopt::Long::Configure ("bundling");

real    0m3.019s
user    0m2.020s
sys     0m0.200s
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem. In what way is your program getting slowed? By how much? How do you know?

Comment: Please show exact benchmarking results showing this to be the case consistently. My initial testing has no performance impact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `bundling` obviously slows down the initial processing (since you now have to parse the argument string for a varied combination of sub-strings), you seem to incur at most 4% system time and 1% user time increase **for an empty script**. Compared to the cost of actually running the script, that should not be terribly significant. I admit I'm not sure about real time changes - they don't seem too correlated - could this be due to some other factors?